# how to resolve cross-browser(mozilla firefox vs chrome) issues in printing page?

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome, cross-browser

The print preview produced for the same HTML code have completely different output in chrome and firefox for the same A4 size..please help

Comment: Have you set up a print stylesheet? [This](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/) might point you in the right direction.

Comment: What is the difference? Margins? missing elements? extra white pages? What chrome's version do you have? Does Firefox print preview ok? Does Chrome print preview ok? Do both print preview not ok?

Answer (score 0):

Mostly Chrome hand firefox have same output for HTML. if you are having problem you can use different style sheets for the different browsers. [Try this](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/15-techniques-and-tools-for-cross-browser-css-coding)

Comment: can we select different style sheets for different browsers??if yes thn how?

Comment: yes we can use diffrent stylesheets for diffrent browser. <script type="text/javascript">
var browser=navigator.appName;
if browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer" {
document.write("<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"IE.css\">");
}
else if browser == "Firefox" {
document.write("<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"FF.css\">");
}
else {
document.write("<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"generic.css\">");
}
</script>